# Optimization: Accessing pointers in different memory areas

Tags: c, pointers, memory, optimization, memory-management

Assume there is the following case:

```
int** data = calloc(3, sizeof(int* ));

int* dynamicInt = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
int automaticInt = 0;
int stackint[1] = {0};

data[0] = dynamicInt;
data[1] = &automaticInt;
data[2] = stackint;
```

And then you would be navigating through values with, say, `*data[i]`

It seems to me that jumping from heap to stack will even be slower than from heap to another address in the heap.

---

What would be the fastest way of assigning those pointers?
What would be really useful is if someone enumerate the possible variations (e.g: stack-stack: 6(fastest), heap-heap 5, auto-auto 4, heap-stack 3 etc..)

Comment: If you have a normal PC, memory is just memory. There is no difference.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: If it really and truly matters, most modern assemblers have a prefetch operation to preload an address before it is needed.  This can mitigate or remove the first load to cache.

Answer (score 1):

I mean it's all in RAM right? Accessing the stack vs the heap is not signficantly different performance imho. Where you'll take a performance hit is in your spatial cache locality because you will potentially be hopping all over memory and taking cache misses. If you care about performance and must use a scheme like this, you might benefit somewhat by sorting the pointers by their value (which is an address). If your pointers are not changing much, though, you'll still probably benefit from temporal locality in the cache. Not sure this helps, but that's my two cents.

Comment: In this minimalistic example, the performance will surely be of no significance, but if implemented in something like doubly-linked list, containing many elements, when iterating through the entire list (which often happens with dlls), I am sure there is slightly-less insignificant performance difference, hence the hoping through addresses like 1232 and 181381238, sometimes on old processor with l2 on their top :)

Comment: @JuanPabloJuliosEstebaFiores The only performance difference would be related to cache misses. But when you're using dynamically allocated data, there's no guarantee that multiple allocations will be in the same cache line. Unless you have thousands of items in different memory areas and you're accessing them frequently, the effect will be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The will be no difference even if the referenced address was swapped as you do not access it